# Geometrical interpretation of $\int_0^{2a} f(x)\,dx = 0$ when $f(2a - x) = -f(x)$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I have read that if $f(2a - x) = -f(x)$ then
$$
\int_0^{2a} f(x) \, dx = 0.
$$

I have also seen the algebraic proof for it, but I want to know what it really mean in geometric terms. Can I get the geometric interpretation of this property?

Comment: Function $x\mapsto 2a-x$ reflects with respect to the point $x = a$. Think of the case when $a = 0$, property $f(-x) = -f(x)$ defines odd function. This is just a translated version of that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function is odd with respect to $x=a$. That is, the area from $0$ to $a$ and that from $a$ to $2a$ are equal in magnitude and have opposite sign, so they cancel, giving a zero integral. Similar to having the integral of an odd function over a symmetric interval.

An example would be $f(x)=(x-a)^3$.

Answer (score 1):

Shift your coordinates so that $x = a$ is the origin. In other words, define
$u = x - a$ so that $x = a + u$. Geometrically, this measures $u$ units to the right of $a$. Where is the reflected point $u$ units to the left of $a$?
$$
a - u = a - (x - a) = 2a - x.
$$
Thus, the condition $-f(x) = f(2a - x)$ for all $x$ corresponds in the shifted coordinates to the symmetry
$$
-f(a + u) = f(a - u).
$$
Since any integral with respect to $x$ over the domain $[0, 2a] = [0, a] \cup [a, 2a]$ is equivalent to an integral with respect to $u$ over the domain
$[-a, a] = [-a, 0] \cup [0, a]$. In either case, each value on the left has a corresponding value on the right of equal magnitude *but opposite sign*, so the net integral must be zero.

Answer (score 0):

By the King's property of integration, we have

\begin{align}I&=\int_a^b f(x)\,\mathrm dx=\int_a^b f(a+b-x)\,\mathrm dx\end{align}

So, we can write
$$J=\int_0^{2a} f(x)\,\mathrm dx=\int_0^{2a} f(2a-x)\,\mathrm dx$$

Adding both integrals
\begin{align}2J&=\int_0^{2a} f(x)\,\mathrm dx+\int_0^{2a} \underbrace{f(2a-x)}_{{-f(x)}}\,\mathrm dx\\2J&=0\\J&=0\\\int_0^{2a}f(x)\,\mathrm dx&=0\end{align}

Notice that if $a=0$, $f(x)=-f(x)$ simply means, $f(x)$ is an odd function, i.e. it is antisymmetric about $x=0$. In the case of this question, an origin shift of $x=a$ is required. $f(x)$ is still odd and everything else becomes obvious.